# HTML & JavaScript - Passing the scroll action from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scroll

Suppose I have two divs:

```
<div id="control"></div>
<div id="view">(A scrollable list)</div>
```

And I'd like to make it so that when the cursor is parked inside `#control` and the mousewheel is scrolled, `#view` will be scrolled instead. Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: take a look at this plugin https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel Can use it on the control div to animate or scroll the other div

Comment: Have you tried `onscroll` event ?? You can fire a javascript function in `#control` DIV and make scroll the other div

Answer (score 6):

Okay, quick fix that worked for me. Even though the fixed div is not scrollable, as it has no content to overflow its bounds, you can still detect `mousewheel` events. `mousewheel` events contain deltas for the x/y dimensions scrolled.

Note: This works for mice or track-pads, and will give you the proper direction (-/+), regardless of inverted Y-Axis settings (read: Apple's (un)natural scrolling)

Therefore, you can do something like this:

```
var fixedDiv = document.querySelector('.my-fixed-div');
var scrollableDiv = document.querySelector('.my-scrollable-list');

fixedDiv.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollableDiv.scrollTop += e.deltaY;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**not sure what the layout looks like**

but if they're right next to each other you could use

```
#control{pointer-events : none}
```

and change a few things.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/QVRNd/

If the elements are not able to be that close, this won't be much help.

It works by putting the control over the list, and disabling pointer events on the control.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

Document has its function onscroll.

```
document.onscroll=moveSetting;
```

Let say `div1` to be scrolled and mouse pointer should be at `div2`.
So we have to execute the `scFunc()` only if the mouse is at div2. We can achieve this by

```
function moveSetting(evt)
{       var div2Obj=document.getElementById('div2');
        var width=div2Obj.style.width;
        var border=div2Obj.style.border;
       var x=evt.pageX,y=evt.pageY,
       var leftChk=div2Obj.offsetLeft;
       var topChk=div2Obj.offsetTop;
        if(x>=leftChk && x<=(leftChk+width+border*2) && y>=topChk && y<=(topChk+width+border*2)) {
                scrollFunc();       
    }


}

var i,j;
    function scrollFunc() {
       var i=document.getElementById('div1').scrollTop;

       i++;
       i=j-1;

       document.getElementById('div1').scrollTop=i;
       /* manage your code yourself to scroll div1 from here */
    }
```

Comment: .scrollDown ? Didn't heard about it. You are missing some semicolons.

Comment: oh thanks, I deleted that line but I was giving suggestion only.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this, and the only way I could achieve a `onscroll` event on a element is with an active scroll bar, which "floats". Explaining floats : it's position is at 100px from top, when it's scrolled we check if it went up or down, and then we bring it back to it's original position. So remember, you need an active scroll bar (the element's inner content should be higher than itself: you can use multiple `<br>` etc...);

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var defaultScrollTop = 100; /* testing value */

        window.onload = function() {
            var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
            var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

            div1.scrollTop = defaultScrollTop; // Initialize to float

            div1.onscroll = function(event) {
                if (defaultScrollTop < div1.scrollTop) {
                    div2.scrollTop += 100; //scrollDown
                } else if (defaultScrollTop > div1.scrollTop) {
                    div2.scrollTop -= 100; //scrollUp
               }

               div1.scrollTop = defaultScrollTop;                
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The CSS:

```
<style>
    #div1, #div2 {
        max-height: 100px; /* For testing */
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
</style>
```

So, when you scroll inside `div1`, it checks if it was scrolled up/down, scrolls `div2` up/down and sets div1 to it's default scroll value. Hope this trick helps.

PS: You can make the scrollbars invisible if you make some research (`overflow:hidden` is not working because there won't be active scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution. You could listen to event `mousewheel` on your `control` div and scroll the other div `view` based on the amount of scroll performed (value is retrieved using `WheelEvent.deltaY`);

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY

```js
var fixedDiv = document.getElementById('control'),
    scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('view');

fixedDiv.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (e) {
  scrollableDiv.scrollTop += e.deltaY;
  console.log(scrollableDiv.scrollTop);
});
```

```css
#control,
#view {
  width: 500px
}

#view {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#control {
  position:fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="control">Keep your mouse here and scroll</div>
<div id="view">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Take a look to the last example -->

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: could have been a little more verbose answer

Comment: These are answers, not links. Give a code example, tips, and warnings, and links. Not just 1 lonely unsupported link.